# Switch / Toggle dynamically created components

Tags: html, angular

I have two child component in parent component which dynamically created.
My goal is to switch/toggle between this components.

```
<div *ngFor="let device of devices; let i = index">
  <app-standart-view [value]="device.value" (click)="SWICH TO DETAIL-VIEW"></app-standart-view>
  <app-detail-view [value]="device.value"  (click)="SWICH TO STD-VIEW"></app-detail-view>
</div>
```

**Scenario:**

When I click `<app-standart-view>` it hides itself and displays `<app-detail-view>`. But only for that clicked component `index = i`. The rest should don't change.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

you can use *ngIf In ts file you will have to define a variable

```
hide:boolean =true
switchView(){
this.hide=!this.hide
}
```

and in html

```
<app-standart-view [value]="device.value" *ngIf= "hide" (click)="switchView()"></app-standart-view>
  <app-detail-view [value]="device.value"  *ngIf= "!hide" (click)="switchView()"></app-detail-view>
```

Comment: This code switches all the children component. My goal is only switch the clicked element.

Comment: So if I click app app-standart-view it should hide itself but nothing should happen to app-detail-view Is it right

Comment: When I click on `app-standart-view` it should hide itself and display `app-detail-view` vice versa. **BUT**: only for the clicked index.

Answer (score 1):

i'd use an `*ngIf='device.toShow'` directiv in your `<app-detail-view>`

And obviously setting the proper value of `toShow` in your methode that you use ater a click event on `<app-standart-view>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let device of devices; let i = index">
  <app-standart-view [value]="device.value" *ngIf="show" (click)="swichView(i)"></app-standart-view>
  <app-detail-view [value]="device.value" *ngIf="!show" (click)="swichView(i)"></app-detail-view>
</div>
```

For specific index you need to pass index and check index

```
show:boolean = true;
swichView(index:number){
    if(index === 1 ){
        this.show = !this.show;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to switch the element `1`. My goal is to switch the clicked element.